# Using Mac Terminal to Insert a Line into a Textfile that Contains the Filename

Tags: mac, terminal, printing, filenames

I'm using Terminal on Mac, and I have a series of text files that each contain data like this:

```
300.50 253.50
301.00 156.26
301.50 191.57
```

I want to insert a header for the columns where the first is labelled as 'Wavelength' and the second is labelled with the filename so that it looks like this (spacing doesn't matter as long as it is delineated by a space):

```
Wavelength Filename
300.50 253.50
301.00 156.26
301.50 191.57
```

I have a loop that inserts 'Wavelength' into each file, and it works beautifully, but adding the filename is causing me some trouble. Here is the code:

```
for file in *.txt
do
  ed -s $file < <(printf '%s\n' 1i "Wavelength" . wq)   
done
```

I have tried these lines with the altered section in bold:

- -ed -s $file < <(printf '%s\n' 1i "Wavelength" **&& $file** . wq)
- -ed -s $file < <(printf '%s\n' 1i "Wavelength" **&& printf $file** . wq)
- -ed -s $file < <(printf '%s\n' 1i "Wavelength" **&& echo $file** . wq)

How do I do this? Do I need to save the file name as a variable and print the variable? Or can I use a modifier to convert the filename to a string?

Please let me know if you can think of anything. Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't know how to do it your way. But you could do something like:
echo "filename wavelength" > a.out  then cat filename >> a.out, then move a.out filename replacing filename with the labeled filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about the following:

```
for file in *.txt
do
  ed -s $file < <(printf '%s\n' 1i "Wavelength $file" . wq)
done
```

btw, what do the ". wq" and the "1i" do? I haven't seen that before...

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you!!!

The period is to signify the end of the text being added, the wq writes and quits the file

1i inserts a line before the first line. 1 is the line number, i stands for insert